# ReactJS: add class in single element on Hover event

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a group of divs that expand a specific div on hover,
my problem is when I hover on an element all the divs is affected.

I dont know why its happening,

Hope you understand me.

Thanks

[Sample Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/yp3278mw5x)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isHovered: false
    };
    this.handleMenuHover = this.handleMenuHover.bind(this);
  }

  handleMenuHover() {
    this.setState({
      isHovered: !this.state.isHovered
    });
  }

  render() {
    const menuActive = this.state.isHovered ? "active" : "";
    return (
      <div className="slider-menu">
        <div
          className={"menu " + menuActive}
          onMouseEnter={this.handleMenuHover}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMenuHover}
        >
          a
        </div>
        <div
          className={"menu " + menuActive}
          onMouseEnter={this.handleMenuHover}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMenuHover}
        >
          b
        </div>
        <div
          className={"menu " + menuActive}
          onMouseEnter={this.handleMenuHover}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMenuHover}
        >
          c
        </div>
        <div
          className={"menu " + menuActive}
          onMouseEnter={this.handleMenuHover}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMenuHover}
        >
          d
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: You need to keep track of the hover states of the individual divs, and change the class accordingly. The way you have it now, you're using the same hover state for all classes.

Comment: I thought, I can do it just like jQuery.. thank you sir

Comment: so I need to create multiple hover events to achieve this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a single div component with event handlers, then populate it. Example:

```
const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <Menu>a</Menu>
    <Menu>b</Menu>
    <Menu>c</Menu>
    <Menu>d</Menu>
  </div>
)

class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isHovered: false
    };
    this.handleMenuHover = this.handleMenuHover.bind(this);
  }

  handleMenuHover() {
    this.setState({
      isHovered: !this.state.isHovered
    });
  }

  render() {
    const menuActive = this.state.isHovered ? "active" : "";
    return (
      <div className="slider-menu">
        <div
          className={"menu " + menuActive}
          onMouseEnter={this.handleMenuHover}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMenuHover}
        >
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: it is working fine in the link but for me it adds class to all elements even if i am binding **this** with event handler.

Comment: The problem is that state must refer to only one of the elements, not all, hence having a component for each of the <div>s guarantees the single mapping between state and elements.